# Subclipse - How to mark a major revision?

Tags: eclipse, subclipse, revision

How does one go about marking a major revision using the Subclipse plugin? I'd like to mark a project at the end of an iteration such that it's possible to revert if necessary without going through endless changes.

TIA.

Comment: You should ask this on SuperUser, as StackOverflow is for programming questions.

Comment: Will do. Wasn't aware of the existence of SuperUser.com.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/141686/subclipse-how-to-mark-a-major-revision

Answer (score 1):

You should create a new tag. Use the "Branch/Tag" command post commit. This makes a 'tag' copy and is stored in "tags" folder.